# Unity pixelart multiple sprites not cutting corectly

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, png, sprite-sheet

I have drawn a pixelart animation 32x32 pixel size, using Piskel online tool. I saved it as a 32x64 so i have both 2 frames in one png file. Then i included it in Unity and when i cut it in sprite editor i get this edge that appears on the next sprite, that shouldnt. See the picture of the robot above the head there is a line. I cutted exactly 32x32 pixels so that line should not be there.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem once. If I remind correctly, you have to change the [texture setting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html). Change the `filter mode` field to `Point (no filter)`.

I may be wrong, but still I'm sure that your problem can be solved by changing it's texture setting.